# Referencing SVG file from Azure blob

Tags: azure, svg, blob

I just came across a very strange problem:

```html
<div class="logo-holder">
    <img class="sponsorhip-logo-preview" id="LogoPreview"         
        src="http://cdn.insights.bio/uploads/83cfc94c4a8c4f14b3cd050cd7e1c7aa.svg">
</div>
```

Using an SVG file as the source of the image [results with broken image in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZsI3.png)

This image is stored on azure CDN. I do not see any error in Chrome console.

Has anyone come across this problem?

Comment: The content-type in the blob-storage-file is `application/octet-stream` please change it to: `image/svg+xml`

Comment: Could you please have a try with the tag <iframe src="xxx.svg"></iframe> ? I test it in edge, it is ok, but if in chrome it will download the image.

Comment: Hi JamesP, does it work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end, I've managed to figure out thank you to Markus.

During image upload to Azure blob, all files were uploaded with default content-type. This line of code made all the huge difference

```
 if (DoesBlobFileExist(blobName))
                blobName = RenameFile(blobName);
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
            if (blobName.EndsWith(".svg"))
                blob.Properties.ContentType = "image/svg+xml";
```

Answer (score 0):

With the azure blob storage java package you can get the file content type and add it to the BlobServiceClient header:

```
        ClientOptions options = new ClientOptions();
        MimetypesFileTypeMap fileTypeMap = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
        String mimeType = fileTypeMap.getContentType(file.getName());
        HttpHeader httpHeaders = new HttpHeader("Content-Type", mimeType);
        options.setHeaders(Collections.singleton(httpHeaders));

        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
        .connectionString(connectStr)
        .clientOptions(options)
        .buildClient();
```